# How to get the auto-lock setting from general settings on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Any chance?

I want to know if it is set from "1 - 5 minutes" or set to "never".

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Apple won't let you directly access system settings like that. If you are trying to prevent the screen from locking, you can always do something like this:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];`

As far as I know, that is the only thing that you can do to interact with the auto-lock.

Comment: Please tell me, Where should I add this line? In appdelegate.m?